WebOS-manager installation from github on Ubuntu 24.04
I was trying to install WebOS-dev-manager from the GitHub repository via
git clone https://github.com/webosbrew/dev-manager-desktop

but I don't know how to proceed with the installation further.
I tried installing it from the deb file but it showed an error with the libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 and after searching the internet I found out this library is not available for Ubuntu 24.04.
I tried various methods like updating the sources.list but it didn't work.
I'm looking for a proper step-by-step solution to this problem.
PS: The directories in https://github.com/webosbrew/dev-manager-desktop don't contain any build or configuration files. It has only JSON files and I'm not familiar with it.
